# Passing in variables into functions

Tags: python, trigonometry

This is my code uses trigonometry in order to find missing sides on a triangle. It works by using SOHCAHTOA to find these sides.
The problem with the code is that when I try to run the code it gives me a invalid syntax when I call the user defined function: "get_method". 
Please can you tell what is wrong with the code and how to solve this consistent problem that occurs with in my programmes.

```
import math

def get_method(question, method):
    print("Lable the right-angle triangle.")
    question = input("What are you trying to find? Type 'h' for hypotenuse, 'a' for adjacent or 'o' for opposite.").lower().strip()
    method = ""
    if question == "h":
        opposite_verify = input("Do you have the length of the opposite?\n"
                              "Type 'yes' or 'no'").strip().lower()
        if opposite_verify == "yes":
            method = "sine"
        elif opposite_verify == "no":
            adjacent_verify = input("Do you have the length of the adjacent?\n"
                              "Type 'yes' or 'no'").strip().lower()
            if adjacent_verify == "yes":
                method = "cosine"
            else:
                print("There's no way to solve this.")

    elif question == "a":
        hypotenuse_verify = input("Do you have the length of the hypotenuse?\n"
                              "Type 'yes' or 'no'").strip().lower()
        if hypotenuse_verify == "yes":
            method = "cosine"
        elif hypotenuse_verify == "no":
            opposite_verify = input("Do you have the length of the opposite?\n"
                              "Type 'yes' or 'no'").strip().lower()
            if opposite_verify == "yes":
                method = "tan"
            else:
                print("There's no way to solve this.")

    elif question == "o":
        hypotenuse_verify = input("Do you have the length of the hypotenuse?\n"
                              "Type 'yes' or 'no'").strip().lower()
        if hypotenuse_verify == "yes":
            method = "sine"
        elif hypotenuse_verify == "no":
            adjacent_verify = input("Do you have the length of the adjacent?\n"
                              "Type 'yes' or 'no'").strip().lower()
            if adjacent_verify == "yes":
                method = "tan"
            else:
                print("There's no way to solve this.")

    return method, question

def main(question, method):
    angle = float(input("What is the degrees of the angle?"))
    angle /= (math.pi / 180)
    if method == "sine" and question == "h":
        opposite = float(input("What is length of the opposite angle?"))
        hypotenuse = opposite / (math.sin(angle))
        print("The length of the hypotenuse is {}".format(hypotenuse))
    elif method == "sine" and question == "o":
        hypotenuse = float(input("What is the length of the hypotenuse?"))
        opposite = hypotenuse * (math.sin(angle))
        print("The length of the opposite is {}".format(opposite))
    elif method == "cosine" and question == "a":
        hypotenuse = float(input("What is the length of the hypotenuse?"))
        ajacent = hypotenuse * (math.cos(angle))
        print("The length of the ajacent is {}".format(ajacent))
    elif method == "cosine" and question == "h":
        ajacent = float(input("What is the length of the ajacent?"))
        hypotenuse = ajacent / (math.cos(angle))
        print("The length of the hypotenuse is {}".format(hypotenuse))
    elif method == "tan" and question == "o":
        ajacent = float(input("What is the length of the ajacent?"))
        opposite = ajacent * (math.tan(angle))
        print("The length of the opposte is {}".format(opposite))
    elif method == "tan" and question == "a":
        opposite = float(input("What is the length z"))


get_method(question, method)
main(question, method)
```

As you can probably see I have a problem with passing in variables into functions. And yes I know my code is really inefficient, but I am only new to coding so cut me some slack.

Comment: If you're getting an exception, please edit the question to include the full exception traceback. A `SyntaxError` will sometimes be reported on the wrong line though, since the cause of the error is confusing Python about the structure of the code (they're often due to something like a missing closing parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

Since `get_method()` seems to be the problem, let's take a look at it.  First, you were passing in arguments that you ignored and reset, so toss the arguments to this function -- define and call it with no arguments.

I've added a couple of helper functions to simply the `get_method()` code:

```
import sys

def str_input(prompt=None):
    return input(prompt).lower().strip()

def boolean_input(prompt=None):
    return input(prompt + "Type 'yes' or 'no': ").lower().strip() == "yes"

def get_method():
    print("Label the right-angle triangle.")

    question = str_input("What are you trying to find? Type 'h' for hypotenuse, 'a' for adjacent or 'o' for opposite: ")

    method = ""

    if question == "h":
        opposite_verify = boolean_input("Do you have the length of the opposite?\n")

        if opposite_verify:
            method = "sine"
        else:
            adjacent_verify = boolean_input("Do you have the length of the adjacent?\n")

            if adjacent_verify:
                method = "cosine"
            else:
                sys.exit("There's no way to solve this.")

    elif question == "a":
        hypotenuse_verify = boolean_input("Do you have the length of the hypotenuse?\n")

        if hypotenuse_verify:
            method = "cosine"
        else:
            opposite_verify = boolean_input("Do you have the length of the opposite?\n")

            if opposite_verify:
                method = "tan"
            else:
                sys.exit("There's no way to solve this.")

    elif question == "o":
        hypotenuse_verify = boolean_input("Do you have the length of the hypotenuse?\n")

        if hypotenuse_verify:
            method = "sine"
        else:
            adjacent_verify = boolean_input("Do you have the length of the adjacent?\n")

            if adjacent_verify:
                method = "tan"
            else:
                sys.exit("There's no way to solve this.")

    return method, question
```

Now you can call it via:

```
method, question = get_method()
```